# Cannot attach css change for child ? angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```js
angular.element($document[0].querySelector("table > tbody > tr")).mouseover().css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
               
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
             
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="person in contacts | filter:search| offset:currentPage*pageSize| limitTo:pageSize
            |orderBy:'name' ">
                <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.email }}</td>
                
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

So i try to achieve highlighting when mouseon row in table, but i cannot access to child element?

There is no problem when i try to acces tbody, but when i try to acces tr so each row will be highlighted when hover?

What i am doing wrong?

in firefox console tr element has class ng-scope but this just mean that it is connected to controller in my api? so it shouldnt be any problem?

Comment: why not do it the simple way? Through css? `table tr:hover{background:red;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted to do can be achieved in simple css. You dont need to use angular to set css.

```
table > tbody > tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

See this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xxcp767e/